# jQuery retain original value of var when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery `var` that sits within an `.on('scroll')` method. The `var` is detecting the top position of a div, that has a position of `absolute`. However, on scroll, the position changes to `fixed`, which results in the value changing (which I do not want), instead, I want to lock in the original value of the variable.

So, for example, if `fixedTop` has an initial value of `500`, how can I lock that value in, regardless of the fact that the value changes on scroll due to it having a position of `fixed`?

Thanks.

```
$(window).on('load scroll resize', function() {
    
    // Vars
    var fixed = $('.mydiv');
    var fixedTop = fixed.offset().top;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply move those variables OUTSIDE of the scroll listener and remove the load event from the event listener also.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fixed = $('.mydiv');
    var fixedTop = fixed.offset().top;

     $(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
          console.log(fixed, fixedTop)
      });    
});
```